# What's Wrong with Quaternion Rotation in the Game Engine?

Tags: animation, game-engine, transforms

Steps:

- I created two identical objects, and animated them to rotate 360 degrees.
- I used [*euler*](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/User:Pepribal/Ref/Appendices/Rotation#Euler_rotation_modes) for the first object and [*quaternion*](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/User:Pepribal/Ref/Appendices/Rotation#Quaternion_rotation_mode) for the second.
- In the Viewport they rotate the same, but in the *Game engine*
  the second object is rotated differently.

What's wrong with quaternion rotation in the *Game engine*?

[blendfile](http://yadi.sk/d/26ScZNoV7E3yK)

[image]
[image]

Comment: Link to .blend seems to be broken.

Comment: Try CTRL-A > Apply rotation

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2988/cant-update-remove-keyframe-values-from-an-imported-collada-file

Comment: It depends on how you animated them, and it's difficult to tell with the broken .blend file. Euler angles and quaternion angles have different parameterizations, and I'm pretty sure however you're animating the rotation doesn't account for the difference: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conversion_between_quaternions_and_Euler_angles

Comment: @OrelGenya can you reproduce this in a new blend file? If so, please [report a bug](https://developer.blender.org/maniphest/task/create/?project=30&type=Bug) .

Comment: @brita_ I can reproduce this with a new .blend in the 2.72 RC. There seem to be some existing reports too: https://developer.blender.org/T38892 and https://developer.blender.org/T28853

Comment: @gandalf3 I took a quick look, BGE indeed only supports the default euler rotations. The animation curves in BGE are Moguri's area, he is already assigned to that last bug.. so

Comment: This issue seems to be an unsupported feature at the moment. Can someone mark this question as answered. Brita wrote: @gandalf3 I took a quick look, BGE indeed only supports the default euler rotations. The animation curves in BGE are Moguri's area, he is already assigned to that last bug.. so – brita_ Oct 2 '14 at 8:00

Answer (score 1):

From Hawkenfox:

**"This issue seems to be an unsupported feature at the moment. Can someone mark this question as answered?"**

(Okay - I am posting this answer, pasted from your comment, for the purpose of marking this as an answer and closing the question. Please mark as answered.)

**Brita wrote: "@gandalf3 I took a quick look, BGE indeed only supports the default euler rotations. The animation curves in BGE are Moguri's area, he is already assigned to that last bug.. so"** – brita_ Oct 2 '14 at 8:00 – hawkenfox Dec 26 '15 at 3:10

BTW, was this resolved?